# Can't Logout of Unity Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: unity, 17.04, session, logout

I'm having a problem logging out of Unity. When I select logout my system freezes and the only thing I'm able to do is hold the power button for a hard shutdown. Does any one know where I might start to troubleshoot the issue? Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Boot up and open a terminal and run this `poweroff` and tell me if that shuts you down, use `sudo` if it doesn't work without it

Comment: @George Yes I was able to power off  with that command. I'm just at a loss as to why logout freezes the system. This is a fresh install too. Any suggestions as to where to go from here? Thanks!

Comment: Lets try a re-install of desktop: `sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity`

Comment: @George That resolved the issue, thanks so much! I'll make note of the commands you had me use for future reference. Thanks again!

Comment: Let me post an answer

Comment: You can use CTRL+ALT+BACKSPACE to kill X server, then you will land on login screen.